# How to read data from JSON object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have a data like below .I want to read the each `devicename` . How should I read ?

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "devupdate",
        "_type": "driver",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "devicename": "UMBus Enumerator2",
          "driverversion": "6.1.7601.17514",
          "status": "",
          "InstallDate": "",
          "InfName": "umbus.inf"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "devupdate",
        "_type": "driver",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "devicename": "UMBus Enumerator",
          "driverversion": "6.1.7601.17514",
          "status": "",
          "InstallDate": "",
          "InfName": "umbus.inf"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "devupdate",
        "_type": "driver",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "devicename": "UMBus Enumerator3",
          "driverversion": "6.1.7601.17514",
          "status": "",
          "InstallDate": "",
          "InfName": "umbus.inf"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have this data as string or in some file?

Comment: i have a data in string format @ S.Petrosov

Comment: I will recommend you to use one of various JSON beautifiers and try to imagine the structure of this JSON file then you need to create classes for complex types and do deserialization of the JSON string for example with Newtonsoft.Json.Converter

Comment: i have generated classes  from the json data by using http://json2csharp.com/ . Can you help me to read the data from the class .

Comment: Here the code how you can do it http://rextester.com/AWQC17767

Comment: Thanks for quick response!!! working fine now :-)